# What is wrong with my Oracle 11g code. So many errors

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create an Oracle 11g database schema whereby it will create a bunch of tables, add sequences to the primary keys and designate foreign keys etc.

So I've created everything in the Oracle 'Object Browser' and copied the SQL into an SQL script but it seems everything has gone horribly wrong and generates 53 errors including the following:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I really don't understand why as this is copied directly from Oracle itself. Although I still can't believe there's no option to export everything to SQL script when I've already successfully created everything in the Object Browser.

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

I've pasted the code here: http://pastebin.com/gb8dekHB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your sequences first, followed by your tables, indexes and triggers.

Your triggers are referencing sequences that haven't yet been created.

Comment: Thanks! Will give that a go! Any idea why the "invalid character" issue is occurring?

Comment: Can you post line numbers for those errors please?

Comment: It appears Oracle 11G doesn't provide line numbers for errors. All I'm getting back is the following (one example):

CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEE"  
   ( "E_ID" CHAR(8) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
 "EF_NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
 "EL_NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
 "EST_ID" CHAR(4) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
  CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("E_ID") ENABLE 
   ) ;ALTER TABLE  "EMPLOYEE" ADD CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_CON" FOREIGN KEY ("EST_ID") 
   REFERENCES  "STORE" ("ST_ID") ENABLE

ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: I reordered the code and it's still giving the same errors.

Comment: Your constraint requires a different table. Your table script by itself is fine. Try it object by object.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete. Thanks to your comment I've reworked the whole thing and it's now working as intended.